# why hobby_posts_path is not recognized by the system while it is there in rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following along a tutorial inn rails in which we can go the specific branch's category page but i m getting an error that the path sent on click event is not recognized by the app

the code for that page where i used that variable is

```
<% branch_path_name = "#{params[:action]}_posts_path " %>
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <ul class="categories-list">
        <%= render all_categories_button_partial_path, branch_path_name: branch_path_name %>
        <%= @categories.each do |category | %>
        <li class="category-item">
            <%= link_to category.name, send(branch_path_name, category: category.name), :class => ("selected-item" if params[:category] == category.name) %>
        </li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

my all_categories_button_partial helper method is as follow

```
def all_categories_button_partial_path
        if params[:category].blank?
            'posts/branch/categories/all_selected'
        else
            'posts/branch/categories/all_not_selected'
        end
    end
```

and the partial i used inside my helper method are as _all_selected.html.erb

```
<li class="category-item">
    <%= link_to "All", send(branch_path_name), :class => "selected-item" %>
</li>
```

and _all_not_selected.html.erb partial is

```
<li class="category-item">
    <%= link_to "All", send(branch_path_name) %>
</li>
```

but when i click on the link then i got this error

```
undefined method `hobby_posts_path ' for #<#<Class:0x000000000e32de40>:0x000000000d3e1810>
Did you mean?  hobby_posts_path
               hobby_posts_url
Extracted source (around line #2):
1
2
3

<li class="category-item">
    <%= link_to "All", send(branch_path_name), :class => "selected-item" %>
</li>
```

where i have done wrong?

Comment: You miss odd space in "#{params[:action]}_posts_path "

Answer (score 0):

Your path definition has an extra space. It currently is `<% branch_path_name = "#{params[:action]}_posts_path " %>`, while it should be `<% branch_path_name = "#{params[:action]}_posts_path" %>` (Notice the space is deleted after path)